# How to merge 2 gcp project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have 2 different gpc project, one with all my running servers, and another running my firebase app is there a way to merge those 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present there is no GCP options to merge projects, however I have created a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/78489579) to provide this functionality in the future. There is not ETA but any progress on it can be followed at the above link.
As a workaround you can create VM disk [snapshots images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of your VM instances from one project and [move them](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-move-a-vm-instance-between-projects-on-google-cloud-platform-39d1690c73a) incrementally to the other. Once you are completely sure that the migrated VMs are working properly in the destination  project, you can shut down the other project which you can still [restore](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en) within 30 days in case you may need to do so.

I am not familiar with Firebase so you would have to take into account any issues with DNS resolution and domain issues with your application if you decide to move the app in that project instead.